# Как на Макбуке через VPN подключиться к другому компьютеру?

Tags: linux, mac, vpn, macbook

Подключаюсь по VPN в определенную сеть, теперь нужно скопировать папку с проектом но она находиться на другом компьютере под управление Windows но в той же сети. 
Как посредством Макбука/Линукса зайти и скопировать папку?

Comment: А на другом компьютере что есть? ssh-server? ftp? samba? Может быть git репозиторий? И собственно операционка какая? Добавьте данные в вопрос и думаю ответ очень быстро отыщется. Самое первое что приходит в голову это `scp` но для уверенного ответа нехватает вводных

Comment: компьютер на Windows 10

Comment: RDP с шарой по локалке может помочь. на маке ищите клиент на w10 откройте шару.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогда [включить](https://g-ek.com/openssh-server-v-windows-10) на W10 sshd и
`scp -r remote_user@w10_vpn_ip:/path/to/project /local/path/to/project`

Или без заморочек расшарить папку с проектом на W10 и через finder на Mac
<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (откроется строка подключения)
`smb://w10_vpn_ip/sharename` и скопировать проект.

> Но это все в случае если Вам нужно просто забрать копию проекта.
>   Если нужно работать с проектом и поддерживать копию на win10 в актуальном состоянии, тогда нужно настраивать git или другую систему контроля версий.
>
> И естетственно и в том и другом случае понадобятся логин пароль учетной записи w10